# Characters with values on the $p$-adic complex field $\mathbb{C}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Characters $\psi : G \to \mathbb{C}$ from abelian groups $G$ to the complex field $\mathbb{C}$ are well-known and appear all over. Is there an analogue for the $p$-adic complex numbers $\mathbb{C}_p$, that is, characters $G \to \mathbb{C}_p$? Do these obey similar properties such as an orthogonality relation as well as $|\psi(g)|_p = 1$? Could you please refer to me introductory material on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by the $p$-adic complex numbers? The algebraic closure of the $p$-adic numbers is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yes obviously I'm lacking very basic knowledge of this and especially intuition. But I would like to learn. Thus far what I've seen are things scattered online. I'm working on things modulo $p$ and I'm hoping I could translate some of the ideas of the usual analytic number theory in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ over to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: I am not sure how possible it is to pass from working mod $p$ to working over the $p$-adics when it comes to representations of groups, though it is not something I really know anything about.

Comment: Representation of groups? I'm just trying to exploit the simple fact that $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$ if and only if $|a-b|_p \leq 1/p$. Here's a bit of motivation. Say you have an arithmetic function $f$ with values in $\mathbb{Z}$ and a set $S \subset \mathbb{N}$. Suppose you wish to show there exists $s \in S$ such that $f(s) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. One way to go about it is by showing that $\sum_{s \in S} |f(s)|_{p} > 1/p$. If you know that $f$ behaves quite randomly, you'd expect the same behavior modulo $p$.

Comment: If one could write $f$ analytically in terms of characters with values in $\mathbb{C}_p$, one could hope to exploit the randomness in the p-adic valuation of $f$ and show the character sums exhibit enough cancellation

Comment: Of course I'm talking of ideas that are common with typical complex-valued characters. I don't know if similar ideas can be used for $\mathbb{C}_p$; hence the question.

Comment: Ahh, just realized that $\sum_{s \in S}|f(s)|_p > 1/p$ does not imply $|f(s)|_p > 1/p$ for some $s$. Scratch that.. However you could try showing that $|\sum_{s \in A} f(s)|_p > 1/p$ for some subset $A \subseteq S$